# Filter an array containing objects based on another array containing objects in angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am working on angular js and i am new to it. So I am stuck at a problem where I have to subtract two arrays containing objects.

```
For Eg.

var all = [{id:'1',name:'A'},{id:'2',name:'B'},{id:'3',name:'C'},{id:'4',name:'D'}];
var old = [{id:'1',name:'A',state:'healthy'},{id:'3',name:'C',state:'healthy'}];

var newArray = [];
```

Now, I wanted to populate the 'newArray' variable with the objects that are not existing in 'old' list as below

```
newArray = [{id:'2',name:'B'},{id:'4',name:'D'}]
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in angular js? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `Array.prototype.some()`

```js
var all = [{id:'1',name:'A'},{id:'2',name:'B'},{id:'3',name:'C'},{id:'4',name:'D'}];
var old = [{id:'1',name:'A',state:'healthy'},{id:'3',name:'C',state:'healthy'}];

var newArr = [];

all.forEach(function(e) {
    if(!old.some(s => s.id == e.id)) {
        newArr.push(e);
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var all = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'A'
}, {
  id: '2',
  name: 'B'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'C'
}, {
  id: '4',
  name: 'D'
}];
var old = [{
  id: '1',
  name: 'A',
  state: 'healthy'
}, {
  id: '3',
  name: 'C',
  state: 'healthy'
}];

var newlist = all.filter(function(a) {
  return old.filter(function(o) {
    return o.id == a.id
  }).length == 0
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newlist, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Answer (score 0):

A proposal with linear complexity.

```js
var all = [{ id: '1', name: 'A' }, { id: '2', name: 'B' }, { id: '3', name: 'C' }, { id: '4', name: 'D' }],
    old = [{ id: '1', name: 'A', state: 'healthy' }, { id: '3', name: 'C', state: 'healthy' }],
    result = function (array1, array2) {
        var o = {};
        array2.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.id] = true;
        });
        return array1.filter(function (a) {
            return !o[a.id];
        });
    }(all, old);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all related to `AngularJS`. This is a javascript problem, and you can easily achieve this result by using the following code-

```
var new = all.filter(function(element) { 
    var res = $.grep(old, function(el) { 
        return el.id == element.id; 
    }); 
    if(res.length == 0) return element; 
});
```